# Red Hat dynamic partitioning of hardware resources

Tags: virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines

I'd like to understand how easy it is to dynamically reconfigure Virtual Machines on a RHEL server.

Ideally I would like to be able to have the flexibility of IBM's PowerVM.

1. Dynamically reallocate CPU resources (even tenth of CPU) to a partition,
2. Dynamically reallocate RAM to a partition
3. Share/Pool some unused CPU resources

Is this possible at all with RHEL?

Comment: short answer:nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With KVM no, but with LXC yes.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Under KVM you can't allocate resources on the fly (as far as I know). But LXC and other container based virtualization solutions by default use the same resources as your guest system they share RAM and CPU. But you can limit these resources with cgroups: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups.txt

Comment: Thx. I went with PowerVM.